# Image from file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to import an image in html from a path in my computer with the following code and it doesn't work.How should i write it ?

The code:

```
console.log(show.image)
<div id="photo">
    <img src={show.image}/>
</div>
```

in show.image i have the full path to the picture and i'm trying to load it in the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument is not parsed and executed as JS

It's parsed as a path, so it search the path `'{show.image}'` and of course it's wrong

What you can do, is to edit the source argument with js like

```
document.getElementById("photo").src = show.image
```

Or directly create an element with the good src argument

**Edit**: my code is working if the img has the id photo, but you can adapt it easily

**Edit** 2 :

And here is you should implement it

In header off you html, you link your script.js file with your page with this line :

```
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

*Note*: i added "defer" to load the script after the body, that way, document.getElementById will be executed after the image element is created, without it it throw an error

in your body, where you want to put it :

```
<div id="imageContainer">
    <img src="" id="image" alt="image description"\>
</div>
```

and in the script.js file :

```
document.getElementById("image").src = show.image
```

Comment: where should i write this?,as i have written it inside the div with {} and with the photo id but it doesnt work with the error Cannot set property 'src' of null

Comment: i have managed to solve it on my own with something like ```    <Avatar src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/${show1.image}`}> ```